# How to handle async function in redux-observable?

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I am using RxJS and redux-observable.

I am trying to read file in epic. In my case, I have to do it in epic, because some other epic trigger this epic multiple "unknown" times by `expand` operator.

But since FileReader is async, the code below does not work.

What is the correct way especially RxJS way to handle this? Thanks

```
export const uploadAttachmentEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(UPLOAD_ATTACHMENT)
    .map(action => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        return {
          ...action,
          payload: {
            ...action.payload,
            base64: reader.result
          }
        }
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(action.payload.file);
    })
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax
        .post( /* use action.payload.base64 */ )
        .map(uploadAttachmentSucceed)
        .catch(uploadAttachmentFailed)
    );
```

Comment: Personally i would have skipped the hole observer and FileReader and just use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) which is synchronous, faster and not ~33% larger payload, that is if your server can handle binaries (multipart upload)

Comment: @Endless thanks for suggestion, I will definitely investigate FormData later!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fan's answer (as of this writing) is good but has some caveats to it that are important:

- It starts reading the file immediately instead of lazily. So just calling `readFile(file)` starts it even before anyone has subscribed. This is error-prone because it's possible that someone might not synchronously subscribe to it right away and then the `reader.onload` will miss it. Observables are ideally made completely lazy and repeatable factories.
- It never calls `obs.complete()` on the observer, so it's possible the subscription will be a memory leak because it never ends.
- The methods on the observer are not bound, so `reader.onerror = obs.error` won't actually work. Instead you need to either `e => obs.error(e)` or `obs.error.bind(obs)` [See here for reference on why](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1981)
- It doesn't abort the reading on unsubscribe.

Here's how I would do it:

```
function readFile(file){
  // Could use Observable.create (same thing) but I
  // prefer this one because Observable.create is
  // not part of the TC39 proposal
  return new Observable(observer => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      observer.next(reader.result);
      // It's important to complete() otherwise this
      // subscription might get leaked because it
      // "never ends"
      observer.complete();
    };
    reader.onerror = e => observer.error(e);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    // unsubscribe handler aka cleanup
    return () => {
      // LOADING state.
      // Calling abort() any other time
      // will throw an exception.
      if (reader.readyState === 1) {
        reader.abort();
      }
    };
  });
}
```

This pattern can be applied to nearly any API, so it's pretty handy to understand exactly how it works.

---

I hope Fan doesn't mind the critique! I don't mean to offend, just want to share knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Your file reading process does return an Observable. The async process is not handeled properly. I suggest to create an file reading function which return an observable first. then attach it to flapMap()

```
  function readFile(file){
    let reader = new FileReader();
      return Observable.create(obs => {
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            obs.next(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = obs.error;
    })
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   }
```

then in your code you can merge it in like ..flatMap(file=>readFile(file))

Comment: I will try now and let you know results, one thing here `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` is unreachable, need move inside

Comment: If you create a plunker i can help debug. I used similar code in my project. Just a direction really.

Comment: Works nice! Another thing in RxJS 5, it is `mergeMap`, not `flatMap`.